# Angular 10 + PubNub - Problem reading messages from a specific channel

Tags: angular, pubnub

I'm trying to use PubNub to read messages published in a specific channel. Publishing is working correctly.

On my Angular 10 Frontend I'm trying the following:

```
this.pubnubService.subscribe({ channels: ['channel1'], triggerEvents: true });

this.pubnubService.getMessage(this.currentlySubscribedPubNubChannels, message => {
  console.log(message);
});
```

However, no message is received when publishing (via my API or the Debug console on pubnub.com).

On the other side, if I specify a listener, I can receive messages on ALL channels (which is not what I want to achieve):

```
this.pubnubService.addListener({
  message: (message) => {
    console.log(message);
  }
});
```

Can anybody tell me why the general listener is working but listening on a particular channel is not?

Any help is appreciated,
thanks,
Pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubnub-angular2
is no longer supported.

Using the "pubnub" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubnub) package in combination with:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pubnub

seems to do the trick.

```
import * as Pubnub from 'pubnub';
...
export class MyApp {

  private pubnubService;

  constructor() {
    this.pubnubService = new Pubnub({
      subscribeKey : '<SUBSCRIBER KEY>'
    });

    this.pubnubService.subscribe({
      channels: [<YOUR CHANNEL>]
    });

    this.pubnubService.addListener({
      message: ((msg) => {
        // handle event
      }).bind(this)
    });
  }
}
```